# XMLNodeList Weird Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xmlnodelist

Take the following XML as example:

```
<root>
  <lines>
    <line>
      <number>1</number>
    </line>
    <line>
      <number>2</number>
    </line>
  </lines>
</root>

XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//lines/line");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    int index = node.SelectSingleNode("//number");
}
```

The above code will result in index = 1 for both iterations.

```
foreach(XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    int index = node.SelectSingleNode("number");
}
```

The above code will result in 1,2 respectively. I know that // finds first occurrence of xpath but i feel like the first occurrence should be relative to the node itself. The behavior appears to find first occurrence from the root even when selecting nodes from a child node. Is this the way microsoft intended this to work or is this a bug.

Comment: Try `.//number`. This is supposed to make the search from the context node. `//` is for the whole document search and not the context.

Comment: yeah thanks but just removing the slashes worked as well as in my second example. I just think it is confusing that if you are searching for node within a node that // would go back to the whole document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yeah thanks but just removing the slashes worked as well as in my second example.

Removing the slashes only works because `number` is an immediate child element of `line`. If it were further down in the hierarchy:

```
<root>
  <lines>
    <line>
      <other>
        <number>1</number>
      </other>
    </line>
  </lines>
</root>
```

you would still need to use `.//number`.

> I just think it is confusing that if you are searching for node within a node that // would go back to the whole document.

That's just how XPath syntax is designed. `//` at the beginning of an XPath expression means that the evaluation context is the document node - the outermost node of an XML document. `.//` means that the context of the path expression is the *current* context node.

If you think about it, it is actually useful to have a way to select from the whole document in any context.

> Is this the way microsoft intended this to work or is this a bug.

Microsoft is implementing the XPath standard, and yes, this is how the W3C intended an XPath library to work and it's not a bug.